# How to filter the drop down list by using other drop down list in asp.ner MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

everyone, I encounter a problem when I try to filter the drop down list.

The situation is I wish to filter the Agent dropdown list by using the Company dropdown list in same view/form. Since I need to display the Agents that only belong to the selected Company. But I have no idea to do that.

Any solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this 2 link's they may be helpful

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

It's ajax toolkit with control you want.

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/24/asp-net-mvc-tip-37-create-an-auto-complete-text-field.aspx

artical how to use ajax toolkit with mvc.

Hope this will help